# Check all the commands prefix with C-c

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, prefixes

I desire to review all the key-sequences with prefix "C-c"

Issue C-c, it prompts

[image]

and remind that C-h C-n to reference the next page.
I want to view them all simultaneously within a single buffer and tried to C-x 1 with intention of see them in a full-screen buffer.

Unfortunately, such an operation is deactivated in the mini-buffer which C-c invoke, In contrast, grep-find, grep's minibuffer could be manipulated with C-x 1.

How could view all the commands prefix with C-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use <kbd>C-c</kbd>`?` to see all the commands prefixed by `C-c`.  If, by chance, `C-c ?` is bound already, try <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd>